# Row count and insert function

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using the following code to copy from an excel file starting with "Backorder Details":

```
Sub INSERT()

Dim Wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook, wB As Workbook
Dim rngToCopy As Range
Dim countEND As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Sheets("RAW_DATA").Select

Worksheets("RAW_DATA").Range("A3:CA45000").ClearContents
If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.ShowAllData

For Each wB In Application.Workbooks
    If Left(wB.Name, 17) = "Backorders Detail" Then
        Set Wb1 = wB
        Exit For
    End If
Next

If Not Wb1 Is Nothing Then
    Set wb2 = ThisWorkbook

    With Wb1.Sheets(2)
        Set rngToCopy = .Range("A3:BX3", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
    End With
    wb2.Sheets("RAW_DATA").Range("A3:BX3").Resize(rngToCopy.Rows.Count).Value = rngToCopy.Value

End If

With wb2.Sheets("RAW_DATA")
    countEND = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("BY3:BY" & countEND).Formula = "=IFERROR(IF(AND(VLOOKUP(VALUE(AS3);BG_DATA!A:A;1;FALSE)=(VLOOKUP(VALUE(AS3);BG_DATA!A:A;1;FALSE));(AF3>0));"""";""x"");""x"")" 'Check
    .Range("BZ3:BZ" & countEND).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(VALUE(AS3);BG_DATA!A:I;9;FALSE)" 'Vendor'
    .Range("CA3:CA" & countEND).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(VALUE(AS3);BG_DATA!A:J;10;FALSE)" 'Planner
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

MsgBox "DONE!"

End Sub
```

I copied this function from another excel file I've made. It worked pretty good. But for some reason the following part is giving me an error now:

```
With wb2.Sheets("RAW_DATA")
    countEND = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("BY3:BY" & countEND).Formula = "=IFERROR(IF(AND(VLOOKUP(VALUE(AS3);BG_DATA!A:A;1;FALSE)=(VLOOKUP(VALUE(AS3);BG_DATA!A:A;1;FALSE));(AF3>0));"""";""x"");""x"")" 'Check
    .Range("BZ3:BZ" & countEND).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(VALUE(AS3);BG_DATA!A:I;9;FALSE)" 'Vendor'
    .Range("CA3:CA" & countEND).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(VALUE(AS3);BG_DATA!A:J;10;FALSE)" 'Planner
End With
```

Run-time error 1004 - Application-defined or object defined error.
I googled this but didn't find a solution. Excel file was an XLSX and is an XLSM now. Can someone please tell what the problem is?

Comment: if wb1 is nothing then wb2 is also nothing as it's set within an if statement . What value does countend have when you get your error.

Comment: But I have the file with the correct name open... so it shouldn't be nothing.

Comment: But have you actually checked?  "Backorders Detail" <> "Backorders detail"

Comment: Yes, it's exactly the same. I even copied the name from the file and made sure that there is no space. It even was the same file (Backorders Detail) in the workbook I've used the macro before.

Comment: Ok, then use F8 to step through your code line by line and check the address of each range variable as your code proceeds. At some point it must go wrong, If the file name is right, how about the sheet names?, what value is countEND - is it even set?

Comment: I forgot about this feature... It look like it recognizes the Backorder details file and also copies it into the workbook. It looks like it only gets stuck by part I mentioned above... I can't figure out why, because It nearly exactly the same function I've use din another file...

Comment: What to you mean with is it even set? countEND = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row. it also counted 36.000 rows

Comment: Thank you Harassed... it was a lot easier than I thought... look at the formula ; <> ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using semicolon `;` as a delimiter in your formula, but the delimiter depends on the localization of your workbook. Use comma `,` instead:

```
With wb2.Sheets("RAW_DATA")
    countEND = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("BY3:BY" & countEND).Formula = "=IFERROR(IF(AND(VLOOKUP(VALUE(AS3),BG_DATA!A:A,1,FALSE)=(VLOOKUP(VALUE(AS3),BG_DATA!A:A,1,FALSE)),(AF3>0)),"""",""x""),""x"")" 'Check
    .Range("BZ3:BZ" & countEND).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(VALUE(AS3),BG_DATA!A:I,9,FALSE)" 'Vendor'
    .Range("CA3:CA" & countEND).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(VALUE(AS3),BG_DATA!A:J,10,FALSE)" 'Planner
End With
```

Alternatively you could use `.FormulaLocal` instead of `.Formula`, but it will work only in the workbooks where localization defines semicolon as the delimiter.